# Converting birth date to age with age_calc() (package eeptools)

Tags: r

I encountered the following error while trying to convert birth date to age:

> Both dob and enddate must be Date class objects

I checked type of my variable and the class is:

`$ brth_dt: Date, format: "1933-07-21" "1978-06-19" "1952-06-12" "1973-03-07" ...`

Here is my code:

```
library(eeptools)
df$age <- age_calc(df$brth_dt, "2016-09-01", units="years")
```

Thanks!

Comment: From which package you used `age_calc` function.  Based on the function parameters, the second argument is a string, so, you may convert it to a `Date` class.  i.e. `age_calc(df$birth_dt, as.Date("2016-09-01"), units = "years")`

Comment: I'm using the eeptools package

using your suggestion, I received the following error:
"Error in age_calc(df$birth_dt, as.Date("2016-09-01"), units = "years") : 
  Both dob and enddate must be Date class objects"

Comment: For me, it is working fine. `library(eeptools); df <- data.frame(birth_dt = as.Date(c( "1933-07-21", "1978-06-19", "1952-06-12", "1973-03-07")));age_calc(df$birth_dt, as.Date("2016-09-01"), units = "years")
#[1] 83.11475 38.20219 64.22131 43.48634`

Comment: Got it working. Turns out I have some NA values in the date column. Thanks!